# Is there a web interface for uploading file to puush?

Tags: image-storage

I was recently introduced to the puush.me service, which allows file upload. However, I was unable to find a web interface to upload files, and it seemed that all upload had to go through their app.

Is there an alternative technique which allows me to upload files to their servers without installing a program, in a similar fashion to Google Drive?

Answer (score 1):

No. You can only upload screenshots with the program.

Answer (score 0):

I found a web interface to upload files to puush.me service over website or browser.

http://yuikao.com/labs/gomupuush/

This site feature:
- Multi file uploader to puush.me service
- Auto submit/upload
- No registration/authentication needed
- No add-on or program needed
- Also free